Uplift Modeling X-Learner - One model for all treatments or multiple models for each treatment?
I am using an x-learner (and doubly robust learner as well) for uplift modeling. I have a control group and 10 treatments. To start, I have just be creating one x-learner and passing it all the treatments. But now I'm thinking -- would it be better to have 10 separate x-learners, each modeling a different treatment against the control? What are advantages/disadvantages to one metalearner with all the treatments thrown in vs. 10 metalearners with one per treatment?

Generally speaking, 10 Different models will each have lower precision because each of them is exposed to less data. A single model will be more precise because its sample size is larger. However, a single model might be more limited in its functional form - depending how the treatment variable is modeled.

An alternative approach to estimate treatment effects is to use random forests. The advantages of this method are that (i) it is fully non-parametric, (ii) it allows for comparison between each treatment and the control group, as well as across other treatment groups, and (iii) random forests are well-suited for detecting heterogeneity in treatment effects.
For example, the Python package mcf (modified causal forest) provides an easy-to-use tool for this purpose, with comprehensive documentation available on GitHub. Additionally, online workshops offering detailed guidance on implementing this method are available at SEW Workshop.
